# call onto the parent page from html-form response in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, response

I'm quite new to handling form input and responses, and I just ran into a problem how to process the server response.

I have a regular input form, that calls onto a php-file (submit.php) to process the submit. The **submit.php** is executed in an **iframe**, using **curl**.
(info: I can't use an ajax call because of some cross-domain issue)

I want to use the javascript bootstrap modal for displaying the thank you or error message after the form submit.

The form looks like this (simplified) with a response ready to be called on and the iframe I'm submiting the data to on the same page:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" target="iframeAnswer" id="formTest">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="your name here">
  <button class="submitMe" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="Modal" class="modal fade">
    <!-- ... some html for the thank you pop up ... -->
    <!-- ... display set to none for the moment ... -->
</div>

<iframe src="submit.php" name="iframeAnswer"></iframe>
```

Now, I receive answer and process it. 
The return is Json, an array $response["success"] which is either true or false. In case of failure, it also contains an error array.
This is my response handling at the moment after processing the post data:

```
$responseJson = json_decode($response, true);

if ($responseJson["success"] == false) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($responseJson["errors"]); $i++) {
        // echo $responseJson["errors"][$i].' <br />';
        // HOW to process this answer other than echo
    }
}
else if ($responseJson["success"] == true) {
        // echo "Thank you!"; 
        // What to do here to reach parent frame
    }
}
```

My Problem and **where I'm a bit stuck is**: 
I can now echo out a simple "thank you" in the iframe, but I would like to call on a Javascript (bootstrap modal) to have a bit of a nicer response. Or in general do something back in the page not in the iframe.

I'm not sure how to "go back" / "talk" to the page with the form from this place.

How can I call for example the javascript function below in the parent page with the form? Or actually any other function for that matter?

```
jQuery("#Modal").modal('show');
```

I feel like I'm almost there but somehow I'm not connecting the last bits and pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so now after some research and testing, its seems at the end that the answer was quite simple. 
I'm echoing out a javascript script that calls onto the parent page.

Its important to tell the javascript to execute after the page is loaded. Otherwise Javascript tries to execute straight away and returns an error since the document is not yet finished.

You also need to include jQuery and bootstrap in the head of the submit.php file (in the iframe) so the jQuery is executed correctly.
Of course if you don't use the bootstrap modal you don't need to include bootstrap.

added to the head of submit.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is what I added in the server response processing in the submit.php file:

```
if ($responseJson["success"] == true) {

    echo "<script> $(document).ready( function () {";
    // wait for document to load, so the JS doesnt try to execute while document is written
    echo "$('#Modal', window.parent.document).modal('show');";
    echo "}); </script>";            

    }
}

if ($responseJson["success"] == false) {
    echo "<script> $(document).ready( function () {";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($responseJson["errors"]); $i++) {
        // Do something here
        // output with Javascript like in the success handling
    }

    echo "}); </script>"; 
}
```